# Call Javascript from iOS instruments script

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I have a instruments UI automation script for iOS,(in javascript)

I would like to call a .NET web service from this instruments javascript.

Any ideas on this ?

PS: I have tried all other methods (like phonegap, XUI etc etc) without results.

Those work on normal javascript not the ioS instruments Javascript

Comment: have you tried making an ajax call?

Comment: Hi Daniel,i tried xui.js etc... Dosen't those use AJAX calls?

Answer (score 1):

Simply call a command (curl/wget for example) in your js script with the method `performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout` of `UIAHost`.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var host = target.host();
var result = host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/bin/echo", ["Hello host"], 5); // Updated to pass arguments as array

UIALogger.logDebug("exitCode: " + result.exitCode);
UIALogger.logDebug("stdout: " + result.stdout);
UIALogger.logDebug("stderr: " + result.stderr);
```

See : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIAutomation/Reference/UIAHostClassReference/UIAHost/UIAHost.html

Comment: Note : `performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout` is only available on iOS 5+ devices

Comment: performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout, can be used to perform webservices etc. iOS Instruments is compatible only with javascript (and not with jquery, ajax, silverlight etc). If you wanted the instruments to perform any of the other tasks like webservices/file operations etc, use shellscript with this method.